# How to calculate spatial correlation between two variables?

Tags: correlation, spatial

I have a dataset of point coordinates of individuals and different variables of these individuals. I want to calculate if the spatial distribution of a certain variable is correlated to the spatial distribution of a different variable. For example: do patches of large plants have higher predation rates, even small plants within a patch of large plants.
Is it possible to calculate a correlation or a level of significance for these two variables and what software should I use?

Comment: @Ladislav In your answer it would be helpful to compare your recommendations with standard methods of spatial analysis such as the [Ripley cross-K function](http://www.stat.iastate.edu/preprint/articles/2001-18.pdf).  ConfEco, the approach you should take depends on the nature of the data: are they an exhaustive census of a region or are they samples? If samples, then how were the samples selected?  (*E.g.,* quadrats, transects, tracking, convenience, etc.)

Comment: It is an exhaustive census of all individuals in a population